# Expected number of switches

Tags: probability, expectation

Consider the random permutation of $n$ integers $1,2,\ldots,n$. We say that $i$ and $j\;\;(i\neq j)$ are switched if the integer $i$ occupies the $j^{th}$ position and $j$ occupies the $i^{th}$ position after the permutation. Find the expected number of switches in a random permutation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n\ge 2$. Define random variable $X_i$ by $X_i=1$ if $i$ is a partner in a switch, and by $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then the number $S$ of switches is given by
$$S=\frac{1}{2}\left(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n\right).$$
By the linearity of expectation,
$$E(S)=\frac{n}{2}E(X_1).$$

To find the probability that $1$ is involved in a switch, we find the probability that $1$ and $2$ are switched, and multiply by $n-1$.

There are $(n-2)!$ permutations in which $1$ and $2$ are switched, so the probability they are switched is $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$. Putting things together, we find that
$$E(S)=\frac{n}{2}(n-1)\frac{1}{n(n-1)}.$$
This simplifies to $\frac{1}{2}$, which means we have missed a simple argument.

Comment: You are saying the answer is 0.5?

Comment: Yes, that's what the computation says.

Comment: Doesn't feel quite right unless i misunderstood the question...

Comment: Just take n=3, and try this by hand, i don't think i get 1/2

Comment: There are $6$ permutations. Of these, $3$ have $1$ switch, and $3$ have $0$ switches. The mean number of switches is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Yes i definitely misunderstood the question...

Comment: A hand computation also yields $\frac{1}{2}$ for $n=4$. Anyway, the indicator function argument is of a standard nature. But obviously suboptimal!

Comment: I wonder if there is an argument by induction though linearity of expectation works fine

Comment: You can shorten this slighly by saying the probability a particular pair is switched is $\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}$ and multiplying by the total number of possible pairs $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Comment: @Henry: Yes, that is a significant shortening, may be the "reason" for the $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Though I should have said "You can shorten this slighly by saying the probability a particular pair is switched is $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$ and multiplying by the total number of possible pairs $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. "

Comment: @AndréNicolas I was reflecting on your answer. Intuitively it does not seem right that the expected number of switches should not depend on $n$. The more integers you have the more switch I would expect. This is making me question your solution.

Comment: Using simulation in python also shows an increase with increasing value of n.

Answer (score 0):

More of a comment: the general question is how many $k$-cycles there are in a random permutation. This is answered in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/50049/secret-santa-expected-no-of-cycles-in-a-random-permutation), see also [this wiki article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation_statistics#Expected_number_of_cycles_of_any_length_of_a_random_permutation)